# bluetooth not connected in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers

i am using ubuntu 14.04.i have inbuilt Bluetooth button. it is working with my Windows which is dual booted in my machine.but its not working with my Ubuntu. please help me

Comment: Can you put some more information to this

Comment: i have tried the code .rfkill  unblock all. but it gives the wlan hard blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following command:
`rfkill list all`

If it's Blocked, then run following command:
`rfkill unblock all`

This command is used to Unblock Wi-Fi & Bluetooth peripheral devices if they are Soft/Hard blocked by Ubuntu & unable to operate from any S/W switches.

Comment: not working of this comment

Comment: Edit question to include the terminal results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` `lsusb`

Comment: rfkill unblock all gives the result as hard block

Comment: Got to the link follwed and try out given solution [Troubleshooting Arch Linux Wireless Using RF-kill](http://www.bighungrygeek.com/troubleshooting-arch-linux-wireless-using-rf-kill-and-why-im-a-dumbass/)